# Self-Study: If $x \sim \mbox N_p(\mu; V)$ and A is a matrix then how to show that $E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)'A(x-\mu) = 0$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moments, multivariate-normal-distribution, moment-generating-function, quadratic-form

If we assume the random vector $x$ to be normally distributed with $N_p(\mu; V)$ then $E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)'(x-\mu)] = 0_p$. If I am not mistaken, this can be shown using the moment generating function of $x$.

To do so, I would define $z = x-\mu$. In this case, the moment generating function would be $M_z(t) = e^{\frac{1}{2}t'Vt}$. The third moment would then be:

$M'''_z(t) = t'VVe^{\frac{1}{2}t'Vt}+2t'VVe^{\frac{1}{2}t'Vt}+t'VVtt'Ve^{\frac{1}{2}t'Vt}$

If we then evaluate this at zero, then $M'''_z(0) = 0_p$.

However, how would we evaluate the following 3rd moment $E[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)'A(x-\mu)]$ where $A$ is a $p \times p$ matrix? I am not sure how we could use the distribution's moment generating function to show that this odd moment is zero (I assume it is zero). Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the distribution of $(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\prime A(x-\mu)$ is the same as that of $(\mu-x)(\mu-x)^\prime A(\mu-x).$

Comment: All odd order central moments of the multivariate normal is zero ...

Comment: @whuber, thank you very much for your hint. I know that the (multivariate) normal distribution is symmetric. However, I am not sure how this would help me with my current endeavour? Would you happen to have a second hint? Thanks so much!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks for your comment. I don't have any trouble showing what you just stated. However, I am confused by the fact that in my case there is now a matrix $A$ involved. And I just dont know how this changes things.

Comment: The easy way out is to follow up on the comment by whuber. Then it will follow rapidly that the matrix $A$ does not matter for the conclusion!

Comment: When a quantity equals its own negative, either that quantity is undefined or is zero.